# Should I commit App.xcarchive, DistributionSummary.plist, ExportOptions.plist, Packaging.log to a public repository?

Tags: ios, git, react-native

I am developing a React Native app. I have started the app with `react-native init` and it auto-generated the `.gitignore` file in the project root.

After some time, I have tried to create a release and this action automatically created some files and a folder in the directory `ios`:

- App.xcarchive
- DistributionSummary.plist
- ExportOptions.plist
- Packaging.log

These files and this folder are not included in `.gitignore`, Git shows them as untracked, so I need to decide whether to add and commit them to Git or not.

I am sure I don't need to commit `Packaging.log` to Git because it contains the log of the local build of the iOS app.

But what about the other files and the `App.xcarchive` folder? As I see, the `DistributionSummary.plist` contains the information about my development certificate and my app identifier. Is it safe to share this?

Answer (score 0):

In my project I added xcarchive file to gitignore as it's almost 200MB in size.